# setAlpha not restore alpha value after animation

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-animation, alpha

As the title, if I change alpha of an `ImageView` by animation, then I can't set back by `setAlpha`:

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);

myImage.animate().alpha(0).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myImage.setAlpha(100);
    }
});
```

Animation is ok, but after this alpha of *myImage* is not set back by `setAlpha`, it's ever zero. Why?

Comment: @MHP no, whatever the value, don't work.

Answer (score 0):

From the Android documentation:

> ImageView.setAlpha(int): This method was deprecated in API level 16. Use setImageAlpha(int) instead.

I suspect you are actually calling the inherited method [View.setAlpha(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)) which takes a  value between 0 and 1. Setting it to 100 is not a valid value.

Either use `setAlpha(1.0)` or perhaps change the method to `setImageAlpha(100)`.

Comment: nope, both solutions doesn't works. The only one seems use animation with 0 time: 'ImageView.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(0)'